# Jetty 11 with Jersey is not accepting requests

Tags: java, web-services, servlets, jersey, jetty

I am learning java web application and started with jetty and jersey for creating the rest api. I am following this article https://mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jersey-and-jetty-http-server-examples/#start-jersey-jetty-application

By this, I am able to compile and run the server however it does not accept any requests. I tried telnet, curl and other things - I always get connection refused.

My `MainApp.java` looks like this

```
public class MainApp {

    public static final String BASE_URI = "http://localhost:8080/";

    public static Server startServer() {

        // scan packages
        // final ResourceConfig config = new ResourceConfig().packages("com.mkyong");

        final ResourceConfig config = new ResourceConfig(Receiver.class);  -- This is my resouce. 

        final Server server =
                JettyHttpContainerFactory.createServer(URI.create(BASE_URI), config);

        return server;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {

            final Server server = startServer();

            Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(() -> {
                try {
                    System.out.println("Shutting down the application...");
                    server.stop();
                    System.out.println("Done, exit.");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Logger.getLogger(MainApp.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
                }
            }));

            System.out.println(
                    String.format("Application started.%nStop the application using CTRL+C"));

            // block and wait shut down signal, like CTRL+C
            Thread.currentThread().join();

            // alternative
            // Thread.sleep(Long.MAX_VALUE);       // sleep forever...
            // Thread.sleep(Integer.MAX_VALUE);    // sleep around 60+ years

        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MainApp.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }
}
```

Am I missing any other configuration? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Should ```server#start``` method be called?

Comment: I checked the above blog again it is not present there. I tried adding server.start(). but now it is giving me null pointer exception.

Comment: @zysaaa : I checked , server value is returned null in 

final Server server =
                JettyHttpContainerFactory.createServer(URI.create(BASE_URI), config);

Comment: When you create the server, add `server.setDumpAfterStart(true);`, if that server dump doesn't show up, then your server hasn't been started.  If it does show up, it will tell you the configuration that is being used, which will also help diagnose things.

Comment: You are using Jersey 3.x, right?

Comment: Can you share the Receiver class? I copied your code and it works well for me.

Comment: @jan.supol : Hey it starts working for me as well, doing nothing.. It was some intermittent issue. Thanks